# Proving that $det(A) \ne 0$ with $A$ satisfying following conditions.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, determinant

I am given $A \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ which satisfies the following conditions.

1. $A_{i,i} \gt 0$ for all $1 \le i \le n$
2. $A_{i,j} \le 0$ for all distinct $1 \le i, j \le n$
3. $\sum_{j=1}^n A_{i,j} \gt 0$ for all $1 \le i \le n$

Then, I am supposed to show that $det(A) \ne 0$

Now, I am frankly not sure where to even start. However, I was given the following hint:

If not, there is a non-zero solution of $Ax = 0$. If $x_i$ has largest absolute value, show that the $i$th linear equation from $Ax=0$ leads to a contradiction.

I don't really quite get how to apply this hint either. Could someone help? Thanks.

Comment: It looks like a Laplacian matrix with positive weight. But Laplacian matrix $\mathbf{L}$ satisfies $\sum_{i} L_{ij} = \sum_{j} L_{ij} = 0$ which gives $\det(\mathbf{L}) = 0$.

Comment: @dmsj djsl If $det (A) =0$  then the columns of $A $ are linearly dependent, as suggested by the hint. I'd try to use this i n conjunction with the three conditions to get a contradiction.

Comment: Google "diagonally dominant matrix".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $Ax = 0$. Then, let $x_i = \arg \max |x_j|$ i.e. $i$ is such that $|x_i| \geq |x_j|$ for all $i \neq j$. By assumption, if $x \neq 0$ then $|x_i| > 0$.

Note that $Ax = 0$ implies that $A_i \cdot x = 0$, where $A_i$ denotes the $i$th row of $A$, as a vector. This follows from the definition of matrix multiplication.

However, $A_i \cdot x = \sum_{j} A_{ij}x_j$. By definition, we have $|x_i| \geq |x_j|$ for all $j$, so write $$A_i \cdot x = A_{ii}x_i + \sum_{j \neq i} A_{ij}x_j$$ and use the inequality $|x+y| \geq |x| - |y|$, to see that :
$$
|A_i \cdot x| \geq |A_{ii}x_i| - \left|\sum_{j \neq i} A_{ij}x_j\right|
$$

But, we know that $|x_j| \leq |x_i|$, so it follows that $$|\sum_{j \neq i} A_{ij}x_j| \leq \sum_{j \neq i} -A_{ij}|x_j| \leq -|x_i|\sum_{j \neq i}A_{ij}$$.

Therefore, 
$$
|x_i|A_{ii} - \left|\sum_{j \neq i} A_{ij}x_j\right| \geq |x_i| \times \sum_{j} A_{ij} > 0
$$

Which is a contradiction, since $A_i \cdot x = 0$. Consequently, no such $x$ exists.

---

More can be said. Indeed, the Gerschgorin circle theorem guarantees that every eigenvalue lies with a Gerschgorin disc, whose centre is one of the diagonal entries, and radius is the sum of the absolute values of the non-diagonal entries of the row.  In this case, by the conditions given, the theorem gives that no eigenvalue can in fact be smaller than the smallest value of $\sum_{j} A_{ij}$, which is greater  than $0$. So this way the result is clear.

Also, the matrix with conditions given is strictly diagonally dominant, and from the Gerschgorin circle theorem is non-singular (known as the Levy-Desplanques theorem, and having applications in probability).